Using PluginManagement and DependencyManagement for versions from parent
Assume I have a parent POM like this (simplified):
<project>
  <artifactId>foo-parent</artifactId>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    <dependency>
  <dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</projects>

And a POM inheriting from it
<project>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>foo-parent</artifactId>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>foo-child</artifactId>

  ...
  <dependencyMangement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.16</version>
      <dependency>
    <dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <build>
    <pluginManagment>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.5.1</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagment>
  </build>
</projects>

Based on what described in https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management, it mentioned that dependencyManagement would affect the dependency resolved transitively.
I was expecting that, when I build foo-child, I will be using surefire 3.5.1 and slf4j-api 2.0.16, as I was expecting dependencyMangement and pluginManagement to affect the versions I "transitively" inherited from foo-parent.  However I found that foo-child is still using surefire 3.0.0-M5 and slf4j-api 2.0.0.
Does it mean that, versions defined in parent's dependencies / plugins are not affected by dependencyManagement/pluginManagement as they are not treated as "transitive" (or other reasons)?
Then I take a step forward, by explicitly declaring dependency / plugin in my foo-child POM without mentioning version, by adding:
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <dependency>
  <dependencies>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</projects>

(of course, the dependencyManagement and pluginManagement is kept there)
Now foo-child will have slf4j-api:2.0.16 resolved, but surefire-plugin is still 3.0.0.
How to explain the difference in behavior between dependencyMangement & pluginManagement in this case?
I am using Maven 3.9.6.

Elements of the parent POM are not transitive dependencies.
Transitive dependencies are dependencies of your dependencies.
In addition to overriding transitive dependency versions, the dependencyManagement also fills in the versions of dependencies without version.
This should also work for pluginManagement and I don't know why it failed in your case.
